# ArrayList Error

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make an ArrayList of my own type to store some values. However, I'm getting an error "x cannot be resolved or is not a field", where is source for example.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class myClass {

public static void main(String args[]){
    addEdge("a","b", 10);
}

private static void addEdge(String source, String destination, int cost) {
      List<Edge> add = new ArrayList<Edge>();
      add.source = source; //error: source cannot be resolved or is not a field
      add.destination = destination; //error: destination cannot be resolved or is not a field
      add.cost = cost; //error: cost cannot be resolved or is not a field
}
}

class Edge{
    String source;
    String destination;
    int cost;
}
```

As you can see I get errors in my addEdge method. I'm

Comment: `add` is a `List`. A list does not have the fields `source, destination, cost etc.` you need to access an item *inside* the list first using `List.get(index)` to be able to edit those fields.

Comment: @Sabir, Answers bellow are correct, anyway, I would not use "add" as variable name since it already is a method of List class, so it could be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
List<Edge> add = ... 
add.source = ...
```

you are trying to access `source` field via `add` reference which is of type `List` but `List` doesn't have `source` field (which is what error message is trying to say). You need to access this fields from `Edge`, not from `List`.

So try something more like

```
Edge edgeInstance = new Edge();
edgeInstance.source = source;
edgeInstance.destination = destination; 
edgeInstance.cost = cost;
...

listOfEdges.add(edgeInstance);
```

---

Anyway you should avoid making your fields accessible from outside of your class. They should be private and you should initialize them via constructor or via setters.

Also it seems that each time you are calling your method you are creating new List

```
List<Edge> add = new ArrayList<Edge>();
```

and you are not reusing it anywhere outside of this method which seems kind of pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `List` and `ArrayList` types you are referencing in your `addEdge` method are Java's own `java.util.List` etc., they don't have accessible properties named `source`, `destination` or `cost`.

If the `ArrayList` is your own implementation, it does not feature `source`, `destination` or `cost` fields.

The idiom you want to use here is reference an `Edge` instance and mutate its fields.

To do so, you would do:

```
add.get(x).setSource("some source");
```

That implies:

- Your `List` is not `null` nor empty
- `x` is a valid index
- The `Edge` element at index `x` is not `null`
- You implemented setters/getters for your `Edge` fields

Answer (score 1):

By defining list of type Edge, you dont get field's defined within edge. It's a list where you could add/remove/iterate elements within it.

In your case, List can only add object of type Edge. So you need to create Edgle like:

```
 List<Edge> add = new ArrayList<Edge>();
 Edge edge = new Edge(source, destination, cost);//add constructor to your edge class like public Edge(Source source... ){ this.source = source;.. }
 add.add(edge);//rename list to meaningful name like edgeList
```